# How do I give some disk time to other applications while zipping a huge folder? C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, zip

I have a huge folder that has to be zipped every night by an application. However, it takes away major disk performance during that period of time and can last for 10 minutes. I want to make it a thread and pause it for 2 seconds and unpause for another 2 seconds like a cycle. I don't mind it lasting longer because I want it to still give some disk time to other applications

START > pause 2 sec > resume 2 sec > pause 2 second > resume 2 sec >......FINISH

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    zipFolder(@"c:\example\start", @"c:\example\result.zip");
}
static void zipFolder(string startPath, string zipPath)
{
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
}
```

Comment: Your best bet is to use something else other than `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory`

Comment: LIke how? Can't I turn it into a thread and control it by pausing and resuming it?

Comment: Is the folder full of files, or just 1 file in particular?  You could always batch the zip operation by adding to it, one group of files at a time, until you reach the end, with your pause in between each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use a library like `DotNetZip`

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

Then you can create a simple wrapper like below.

```
public class ScheduleZipper
{
    private int _interval;
    private DateTime _lastZip;
    private string _source;
    private string _dest;

    public ScheduleZipper(string source, string dest, int interval)
    {
        _interval = interval;
        _lastZip = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(_interval);
    }

    private void ZipFilesInFolder(string path, ZipFile zip)
    {
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
        {
            if (DateTime.Now >= _lastZip.AddMilliseconds(_interval))
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(_interval);
                _lastZip = DateTime.Now;
            }
            zip.AddFile(file);
        }

        foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            ZipFilesInFolder(path, zip);
        }
    }

    public void Zip()
    {
        using (var zip = new ZipFile(_dest))
        {
            ZipFilesInFolder(_source, zip);
        }
    }
}
```

And simply do something like this

```
var schedule = new ScheduleZipper(@"c:\example\start", @"c:\example\result.zip", 2000);
schedule.Zip();
```

If your program is doing other stuff then you could wrap it into a thread.

Note: You might want to modify the code to create your zip archive like you want it, with folders etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485716(v=vs.110).aspx

Create the thread and in the thread add an entry and pause afterwards.